# JavaScript and function overload clarification

Tags: javascript

I was reading [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://www.manning.com/resig/) and I saw this code which produces a function overload:

```
function addMethod(object, name, fn)
{
        var old = object[name];
        object[name] = function ()
        {
                if(fn.length == arguments.length) return fn.apply(this, arguments)
                else if(typeof old == 'function') return old.apply(this, arguments);
        };
}

function Ninjas()
{
        var ninjas = ["Dean Edwards", "Sam Stephenson", "Alex Russell"];
        // addMethod is defined in Listing 2-28
        addMethod(this, "find", function ()
        {
                return ninjas;
        });
        addMethod(this, "find", function (name)
        {
                var ret = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < ninjas.length; i++)
                if(ninjas[i].indexOf(name) == 0) ret.push(ninjas[i]);
                return ret;
        });
        addMethod(this, "find", function (first, last)
        {
                var ret = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < ninjas.length; i++)
                if(ninjas[i] == (first + " " + last)) ret.push(ninjas[i]);
                return ret;
        });
}

var ninjas = new Ninjas();


assert(ninjas.find().length == 3, "Finds all ninjas");
assert(ninjas.find("Sam").length == 1, "Finds ninjas by first name");
assert(ninjas.find("Dean", "Edwards").length == 1, "Finds ninjas by first and last name");
assert(ninjas.find("Alex", "X", "Russell") == null, "Does nothing");

function assert(a,b)
{
  if (a==true) console.log(b) ; else console("----");
}
```

As far as I understand, the `addMethod` always keeps the `old` value of the function (via closure).

So finally, there is  *one* function which checks a condition, and if it fails, it invokes the `old` function which *in turn does the same thing*.

However I don't understand the evaluation of `arguments.length` (I know the differences between `function().length` and `argument.length`).

To which rectangle does `arguments` refer to?

[image]

I tracked it  in debugger, and I'm getting confused because at first, the function registers (so `arguments.length` is 3 `[(object, name, fn)]`, but later it is invoked so now there are another arguments.

How is that working?

[**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/ecebel/3/edit)

Comment: The [MDN docs on `arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) might be of assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But does arguments refers to : (which rectangle ?)

The 2nd -- `object[name] = function ()`

`arguments` will always refer to the object for the inner-most `function` declaration/expression. The `arguments` of any *outer* `function`s, such as `addMethod(object, name, fn)`, will be shadowed and rendered inaccessible since they all use the same identifier.

---

It's comparing the number of arguments that were named (`fn.length`) to the the number of arguments passed in (`arguments.length`), using the 1st match. So that:

```
ninjas.find()                       // (0 == 0), uses `function ()`
ninjas.find("Sam")                  // (1 == 1), uses `function (name)`
ninjas.find("Dean", "Edwards")      // (2 == 2), uses `function (first, last)`
ninjas.find("Alex", "X", "Russell") // (? == 3), no match, returns `undefined`
```

Comment: +1 It might be worth mentioning that at first time (`ninja.find()`),  sees the **3 overload** function and then activates the **2 overload** function and when it still doesnt find it , it goes again....and again...

Comment: @RoyiNamir Well, it doesn't activate the "*overloads*" directly until it has a match. It's only calling the anonymous function created within `addMethod`. This acts as a kind of linked-list loop of `old` references, climbing down a "*rabbit hole*" of closures until it either finds a match or reaches the bottom.

Comment: The `this` in `fn.apply(this` referes to the `object` in `object[name] ={..}` right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir `this` will be `ninja` because the 1st is called as `ninja.find(...)` and keeps passing the reference to `ninja` along with `old.apply(...)`.

Comment: why he didn't do : `fn.apply(object, arguments)` ? object _is_ the ninjas object

Comment: @RoyiNamir So, if the method is actually called with another context -- `ninja.find.call({})` -- it's able to keep it throughout. Using `fn.apply(object, ...)` would be similar to `ninja.find.bind(ninja)`.

Comment: p.s. i'll be glad to hear you solution to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274927/create-only-one-instance-of-constructor-function.  ( maybe you have a better solution).

Comment: @RoyiNamir It's actually got some good answers already for both eager- and lazy-loaded singletons. But, tossed a few variations in a Gist: https://gist.github.com/coiscir/5115095.

Comment: I had the same confusion with regard to what `arguments` was referring to?
The point to consider is that while `fn.length` is fixed during function definition (compile time), `arguments.length` is evaluated only during a function call. And if `arguments.length` can match any `fn.length` during a particular run, then it calls that function else move onto the other  function calls until it finally runs dry.