# Create only one instance of constructor function?

Tags: javascript

I have a *part* of plugin which uses private variables and exposes *public* method  :

[**JSBIN 1**](http://jsbin.com/ekowoj/1)

```
function  myWorld()
    {
      var myPrivate=1;
      this.do1=function (){alert(myPrivate);} ;
    }

var a=new  myWorld();

a.do1() //1
alert(a.myPrivate); //undefined (as it should be)
```

But I want to prevent doing this again : `new  myWorld();`

The only option I know is with object literal :

[**JSBIN 2**](http://jsbin.com/ekowoj/2/)

```
var myWorld=
    {
      myPrivate:1,
      do1:function (){alert(this.myPrivate);} 
    }


alert(myWorld.myPrivate); //1 ( ouch....)
myWorld.do1() //1
```

**Question**

How can encapsulate private fields and still prevent uses from `myWorld` to be instanced `>1 times` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures are a great tool to define the scope:

```
  var myWorld= (function(){
    var myPrivate = 1;
    return {
      do1:function (){alert(myPrivate);} 
    }
  }());


   myWorld.do1();
```

You might want to check out the free [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) book

Answer (score 2):

Try something along these lines:

```
(function(){
  var instanciated = false;
  window.myWorld = function() {
    if( instanciated) throw new Error("myWorld can only be instanciated once!");
    instanciated = true;
    var myPrivate = 1;
    this.do1 = function(){alert(myPrivate);};
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the private variable inside an IIFE:

```
var myWorld = (function() { 
    var myPrivate = 1;
    return { ... };
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = new function myWorld()
{
  var myPrivate=1;
  this.do1=function (){alert(myPrivate);} ;
}
```

This makes `myWorld` available only inside the function. If you don't event want it accessable there, then remove the name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a singleton pattern to maintain one instance of the object. Something like:

```
(function (global) {
    var _inst;

    global.myWorld = function () {
        if (_inst) throw new Error("A myWorld instance already exists. Please use myWorld.getInstance()");
        _inst = this;
    };

    global.myWorld.prototype = {
        do1: function() {
            console.log("do1");
        }
    };

    global.myWorld.getInstance = function() {
        if (_inst) return _inst;
        return new myWorld();
    };
}(window));

var world = new myWorld();
var world2 = myWorld.getInstance();
console.log(world === world2); // true
var world3 = new myWorld(); // throws Error
```